# Change word document template footer and header using C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office

I want to create a word document using exiting word document template.
So i try like this

```
private void CreateWordDocument(object fileName,
                                object saveAs)
{
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;           
    var wordApp = new Application();         
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = null;

    if (File.Exists((string)fileName))
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = false;

        //Set Word to be not visible.
        wordApp.Visible = false;

        //Open the word document
        aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
            ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing);

        aDoc.Activate();

        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Name>", txtName.Text);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<company>", txtcompanyName.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    //Save the document as the correct file name.
    aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    //Close the document - you have to do this.
    aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

In my template footer and header part have some variables.
But I don't know how to replace it using variables..

my header like this.
[image]

How to do it?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same requirement of editing the existing word template including headers and footers. Here is the solution which I used and works perfectly fine.

To replace words in the word template:

```
    string destFile = Server.MapPath("~/Letters/sample.docx");
    object fileName = destFile; 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = false };
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
    object Unknown = Type.Missing;
    aDoc.Activate();
    try
    {
     //Replace any text inside the word document
     FindAndReplace(wordApp, "[Date]", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    }
```

To replace words in the footer of the word template:

```
    object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in aDoc.Sections)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeadersFooters footers = section.Footers;
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter footer in footers)
                    {
                        Range footerRange = footer.Range;
                        footerRange.Find.ClearFormatting();
                        footerRange.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting(); 
                        footerRange.Find.Text = "[Vendor Specialist Phone]";
                        footerRange.Find.Replacement.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["phoneNumber"].ToString();
                        footerRange.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                        footerRange.Find.Execute(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref replaceAll, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
                    }
                }
            aDoc.SaveAs(ref fileName,
            ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
            ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
            ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                //Close the document
                aDoc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
                //Close the instance of WINWORD.EXE
                ((_Application)wordApp).Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
            }
```

To replace headers, its same as footers. Just use section.Headers instead of section.Footers. Rest everything is same.

This works fine without any problem.

Thank You